# Why doesn't the method of moments work when calculating the variance of the inverse gamma distribution?

Tags: r, variance, method-of-moments, inverse-gamma-distribution

I'm trying to calculate the variance of the inverse gamma distribution using the method of movements. According to wikipedia the variance should be:

$$\sigma^2 =\frac{\beta^2}{(\alpha-1)^2(\alpha-2)}$$

Where $\alpha$ is the shape and $\beta$ is the scale of the inverse gamma distribution. When trying this out in R it works reasonably well when $\alpha$ is not to close to 2. For example:

```
library(MCMCpack) # for the rinvgamma function
a <- 10
b 100

# The variance according to the method of movements
b^2/((a-1)^2*(a-2)) 
## 15.4321

# The variance by generating inverse gamma distributed random numbers and
# calculating the sample variance
var(rinvgamma(n=9999, shape=a, scale=b)) #
## 15.84388
```

But when $\alpha$ gets close to 2 the method of movements doesn't seem to work anymore. In the following example the sample variance is much smaller than the method of movements variance:

```
a <- 2.2
b <- 100

# The variance according to the method of movements
b^2/((a-1)^2*(a-2)) 
## 34722.22

# The variance by generating inverse gamma distributed random numbers and
# calculating the sample variance
var(rinvgamma(n=9999, shape=a, scale=b)) # 
##14479.56
```

Why doesn't the method of movements work? Am I doing something wrong that can be fixed or is there some other way that I can calculate the variance of an inverse gamma distribution?

Comment: With such a huge theoretical variance, you need a quite large sample to estimate it accurately. Even with the normal distribution you will observe discrepancies `var(rnorm(10000,100,35000))` (less severe, of course).

Comment: When $\alpha \rightarrow 2$, the variance goes to infinity. You cannot hope to approach "infinity" accurately

Comment: @Procrastinator: sorry, we have posted at the same time!

Comment: for small $\hat{\alpha}-2$ the variance of the estimate may be infinite (I haven't checked, but I'd expect that to be the case).

Comment: @Procrastinator . So the method of moments version is the one that is correct and sample variance is the one that is off?

Comment: @RasmusBååth Well, you are not using the method of moments precisely. The expression `b^2/((a-1)^2*(a-2))` is actually the theoretical variance. The method of moments consists of solving the system $\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha-1}=\bar{x}$ and $\dfrac{\beta^2}{(\alpha-1)^2(\alpha-2)}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n(x_j-\bar{x})^2$ in terms of $(\alpha,\beta)$. After this, you could plug the solutions $(\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta})$ into the expression for the variance $\dfrac{\beta^2}{(\alpha-1)^2(\alpha-2)}$ in order to obtain an estimator of this quantity.

Comment: @Procrastinator. Ah, ok... Thank you so much for clearing that up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made this community wiki so as not to take any credit for @Procrastinator or anyone else's solution, but this question does have an answer.

The first element to consider is that if the true distribution's $\alpha$ is approaching 2 from above, the true variance approaches infinity. Therefore, even if the variance is finite, as $\alpha$ approaches 2 from above, the "true" variance grows similar to $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}$ (hyperbolically?) and the number of simulations needed to capture that extraordinary growth may well be intractable within any feasible time scale (like a human life). The Central Limit Theorem only holds in cases of finite variance, and as the variance gets out of control, its power weakens. For all we know, the third moment is already infinite and the Berry-Esseen theorem no longer holds, and even though the variance is finite, the rate of convergence is completely unknown and almost certainly glacial. The 9,999 observations in the question simply weren't enough to capture the tail.

A second important point is that
$$
\sigma^2=\frac{\beta^2}{(\alpha−1)^2(\alpha−2)}
$$
is the true distribution given know $\alpha$ and $\beta$. When using method of moments, we are making the inference in the opposite direction. We have known empirical $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{s}^2$ from which we want to estimate an $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$. Running through the algebra, if I have not made an error, what is actually being solved is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{\alpha} &= \frac{\bar{x}^2}{\bar{s}^2}+2\\
&=\frac{1}{CV^2} + 2\\
\hat{\beta} &= \left(\frac{\bar{x}^2}{\bar{s}^2}+1\right)\bar{x}\\
&=\left(\frac{1}{CV^2} + 1\right)\bar{x}
\end{aligned}
$$

While the Law of Large Numbers says these estimates will asymptotically approach their true values, once again, the rate of convergence may be on the order of the heat-death of the universe, and this is more likely as the parameters approach their hard limits. For an inverse gamma with a true $\alpha \leq 2$ there is no finite number of simulations whose variance would be captured by MoM. Practically, as the function has a $+2$ in it, but more importantly, as the true variance is infinite, the sum of squared errors does not converge. Similarly, For an inverse gamma with a true $\alpha \leq 1$ there is no finite number of simulations whose mean would be captured by MoM. Practically, note the $+1$. More importantly, in this case, as more observations are generated, larger and larger values are seen and the mean diverges.

Comment: In short the variance is only defined for $\alpha>2$ and the mean for $\alpha>1$. One should use alternative measurements like harmonic mean rather than the mean and full width half maximum (FWHM) for a measure of dispersion rather than the variance.

Comment: The meaning of "huge" variance in your second paragraph is unclear.  After all, one could take a beautiful textbook example where MoM works nicely (a Normal distribution, for instance) and just rescale all the data to create a "huge" variance according to any quantitative criterion.  Something deeper than that must underlie your sense of "huge," but what is it specifically?

Comment: I was not as precise as I should be, the main issue isn't the variance per se, as you correctly point out, it is $\alpha$ approaching 2, which manifests a variance whose exponent can be measured with five or ore digits. I'll think about how to re-write it better. Also, this is community wiki, please feel free to correct and enhance; I greatly value your insight and input, @whuber.

Comment: This is a thorny issue.  Since there isn't anything inherently problematic with $\alpha \gt 2$--the variance is still finite--the question must revolve around the estimation procedure.  The solution would seem to located in the chance that with $\alpha \approx 2,$ the sampling variability of the variance will be so great as to preclude precise estimation of $\alpha$ without huge amounts of data. The problem doesn't seem to be inherent in MoM.  This seems to be what you're trying to articulate in the second half of this answer.

Comment: Yes, the variance is finite, but all that tells us is that the convergence of the sample estimator to the true value exists asymptotically. It may only converge at the limit and may require 10^100 terms to get a few measly decimal places: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452053/is-there-a-slowest-rate-of-divergence-of-a-series for some pathological examples. Therefore, I believe "The 9,999 observations in the question simply weren't enough to capture the tail." is clearly the case. The prior sentences may need some refinement.

Comment: The difficulties with convergence have *nothing* to do with the size of the variance, though.  With a simple rescaling of the data, you can make any nonzero variance equal to unity.  Convergence becomes a problem when the *tails are heavy,* as you allude to later in your comment.  But that is not measured by variance.

Comment: I  completely agree, @whuber. Using "huge variance" which is a symptom of the cause "tails too heavy for variance to converge in reasonable time despite its being finite" is misleading. It's the rate of convergence that is the key, and while I and many others intuitively make that linkage, for StackOverflow we should be as precise as possible.